# Which lubricants I need to use for a gear motor?

Tags: electrical, power-windows, grease

I just dismount a micro motor for the electric windows.
I need to lubricate it.
Which is the best way to lubricate the gears? I saw that there is plastic outside. I will not use the MoS2 grease.

[image]

EDIT

I don't have the picture available but I found a similar one gearbox dismounted.

[image]

Comment: You need to find out what the material the gears are made of. The needed type of grease depends heavily if the material is some plastic (possible ptfe enriched?) or metal

Comment: The gears are in stainless steel

Comment: Are you sure?  Usually these have plastic gears.

Comment: I think the best course of action would be to disassemble the entire thing, post photos and describe your entire problem, including the symptoms. Why do you want to exclude MoS2?

Comment: MoS2 is not compatible with plastics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a difficult question as many greases affect plastics. A silicone grease, most likely to be compatible with plastics, won't provide enough lubrication for the metal gears. In your case I'd try to source some ptfe grease, specified for metal/plastic applications.

It is important to disassemble the gear and painstakingly clean the gear from debris or old grease. Also avoid brake cleaner on the plastic parts..

Comment: It would be better an oil or grease?

Comment: In general oil lubrication is better for gears, but more difficult to seal. The best would be the same lubrication as the original one. Also leaking oil (or wrong grease/oil) can make significant damages..